# The webview considers the youtube video path local

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

I have a webview which will load a page that contains some embedded youtube videos; for instance:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/6QGbsNIZ-uo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Unfortunately no embedded video player appears, because of how the src attribute is written

```
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/6QGbsNIZ-uo"
```

Now, is there anyway to make the webview avoid to consider the // as local file? Is there any parameter I could enable/disable to make the video player show? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why you dont write `src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6QGbsNIZ-uo` ?

Comment: because I don't write the page, I simply load it